# Creating a Large List of (Large) Vectors with Rcpp

Tags: list, rcpp

The input of my function consists of two matrices `mat1` and `mat2` and the number of permutations `B`. Both `mat1` and `mat2` have `m` columns, but different number of rows.

The function first permutes the rows of both matrices (while maintaining column information). It then performs some operation that compares columns of permuted versions of `mat1` and `mat2`.

The following is an example of my function `permute_data`. The comparison function `CompareMatCols()` outputs a vector of length `m`.

**Question**
What is the best way to initialize my output list object? I've seen several posts indicating the limitations of `push_back`. *Both* `B` and `m` will be on the order of ~10000, so an efficient way would be ideal.

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <math.h>
//#include <random> //for std::shuffle

using namespace std;
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector ColMax(NumericMatrix X) {
  NumericVector out = no_init(X.cols());
  for(int j = 0; j < X.cols(); ++j) {
      double omax = X(0,j);
    for(int i = 0; i < X.rows(); ++i){
      omax = std::max(X(i,j),omax);
    }
    out[j] = omax;
  }
  return out;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector vecmin(NumericVector vec1, NumericVector vec2) {
  int n = vec1.size();
  if(n != vec2.size()) return 0;
  else {
    NumericVector out = no_init(n);
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      out[i] = std::min(vec1[i], vec2[i]);
    }
    return out;
  }
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
List permute_data(NumericMatrix mat1,NumericMatrix mat2,int B) {

  List out(B); // How to initialize this???, Will be large ~10000 elements
  int N1 = mat1.rows();
  int N2 = mat2.rows();
  int m = mat1.cols(); //Will be large ~10000 elements

  // Row labels to be permuted
  IntegerVector permindx = seq(0,N1+N2-1);
  NumericMatrix M1 = no_init_matrix(N1,m);
  NumericMatrix M2 = no_init_matrix(N2,m);

  for(int b = 0; b<B; ++b){
    // Permute the N1+N2 rows
   /*std::random_device rng;
   std::mt19937 urng(rng()); //uniform rng
   std::shuffle(permindx.begin(),permindx.end(),urng);*/
    permindx = sample(permindx,N1+N2); //Use Rcpp's function to work with R's RNG
    for(int j=0; j<m; ++j){
        // Pick out first N1 elements of permindx
        for(int i=0; i<N1; ++i){
          if(permindx[i]>=N1){ //Check that shuffled index is in bounds
            M1(i,j) = mat2(permindx[i],j);
          } else{
            M1(i,j) = mat1(permindx[i],j);
          }
        }
        // Pick out last N2 elements of permindx
        for(int k=0; k<N2; ++k){
          if(permindx[k+N1]<N1){ //Check that shuffled index is in bounds
            M2(k,j) = mat1(permindx[k+N1],j);
          } else{
            M2(k,j) = mat2(permindx[k+N1],j);
          }
        }
    }
    out[b] = vecmin(ColMax(M1),ColMax(M2)); //a vector of length m
  }
  return(out);
}

/***R
set.seed(1)
X = matrix(rnorm(3*5),ncol=5)
Y = matrix(rnorm(5*5),ncol=5)
B = 5
res = permute_data(X,Y,B)
*/
```

Edit: Added lines to address @duckmayr's point.
Edit 2: Per Dirk's suggestion, I included a minimally complete verifiable example.

Comment: I am not sure if the caveats about `push_back` also apply to `List`, but you could use `std::vector` instead. BTW, I would not use `std::random_shuffle`, since it has been deprecated/removed from modern C++ versions.

Comment: Unrelated note: Have you used the function as it is yet? I have to imagine the line `M1(i,j) = mat1(permindx[i],j);` will sometimes be problematic since the first N1 elements of `permindx` could include one or more elements greater than `N1` (and/or similarly for the last N2 elements and assigning to `M2`)

Comment: @RalfStubner, what alternative would you suggest to `std::random_shuffle`?

Comment: @duckmayr, that is a good point! I tested out the shuffling, but not the matrix allocation.

Comment: You may understand the "limits of `push_back`": you may likely think of a comment for  _performance_ issue. You could avoid it by accumulating in a `std::list` and convert at end when the final dimension is known.  But your question is a little far from a [minimally complete verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so I can't say more.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel, thanks for the feedback - I've edited the post.

Comment: I would use [`std::shuffle`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle) or [`RcppArmadillo::sample`](http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/using-the-Rcpp-based-sample-implementation/).

Comment: @RalfStubner - Thanks. I tried using `std::shuffle` (seed comments in above code) but couldn't get the R RNG to sync with it (using `set.seed()` in `R` and calling my function gave me different results for the same seed). If I recall, isn't the `RcppArmadillo` version older?

Comment: @stats134711 Putting my two cents in, I'd go for `RcppArmadillo::sample`

Comment: Careful. There are at least three RNGs in play.  R, Arma, STL/C++. We make Arma use the one R uses (and that is documented).  You cannot just assume we'd also impact the STL / C++ library one.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel - Do you mean that there is a way to use `std::shuffle` reproducibly with `R`'s RNG? I did not mean to suggest that the one in `R` should always match the one in C++.

Comment: One could write a UniformRandombitsGenerator that wrapps R's RNG, similarly how you wrapped R's RNG for `std::random_shuffle`. However, `Rcpp::sample` is probably the simplest way (totally forgot about that). Are there any questions still open? `std::list` plus `push_back` should solve your main question.

Comment: @RalfStubner - Yes, thank you! You all have helped me greatly.

Comment: How about adding a self-answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, the solution I went with is the one seen above:

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
List permute_data(NumericMatrix mat1,NumericMatrix mat2,int B) {

  List out(B); // Will be large ~5000 elements
  int N1 = mat1.rows();
  int N2 = mat2.rows();
  int m = mat1.cols(); //Will be large ~10000 elements

  // Row labels to be permuted
  IntegerVector permindx = seq(0,N1+N2-1);
  NumericMatrix M1 = no_init_matrix(N1,m);
  NumericMatrix M2 = no_init_matrix(N2,m);

  for(int b = 0; b<B; ++b){
    // Permute the N1+N2 rows
    permindx = sample(permindx,N1+N2); //Use Rcpp's function to work with R's RNG
    for(int j=0; j<m; ++j){
        // Pick out first N1 elements of permindx
        for(int i=0; i<N1; ++i){
          if(permindx[i]>=N1){ //Check that shuffled index is in bounds
            M1(i,j) = mat2(permindx[i],j);
          } else{
            M1(i,j) = mat1(permindx[i],j);
          }
        }
        // Pick out last N2 elements of permindx
        for(int k=0; k<N2; ++k){
          if(permindx[k+N1]<N1){ //Check that shuffled index is in bounds
            M2(k,j) = mat1(permindx[k+N1],j);
          } else{
            M2(k,j) = mat2(permindx[k+N1],j);
          }
        }
    }
    out[b] = vecmin(ColMax(M1),ColMax(M2)); //a vector of length m
  }
  return(out);
}
```